# How to determine if two properties are false inside one ember computed property?

Tags: ember.js, computed-properties

I have a controller with the following properties and computed properties.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  emailAddress: '',
  messageBody: '',

  validEmail: Ember.computed.match('emailAddress', /^.+@.+\..+$/),
  validMessage: Ember.computed.gte('messageBody.length', 5),

  enableSend: Ember.computed.and('validEmail', 'validMessage'),
  disableSend: Ember.computed.not('enableSend')
});
```

This controller is tied to a simple form that has an email input field and text box. I want to check if both the email input and text box are valid before I enable the submit button.

The above code works just fine, however, it seems like there has to be a way to combine the logic in `enableSend` and `disableSend`

Apparently you can't chain methods on computed properties but something like this would make sense:

```
Ember.computed.and.not('validEmail', 'validMessage')
```

This may be a dumb question but how do I determine if two values are false without having to write two computed properties?

Answer (score 1):

Write the computed property long-hand:

```
disableSend: Ember.computed('validEmail', 'validMessage', function() {
  return this.get('validEmail') && this.get('validMessage');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a re-factored version of the JS code:

```
emailAddress: '',
messageBody: '',

validEmail: Ember.computed.match('emailAddress', /^.+@.+\..+$/),
validMessage: Ember.computed.gte('messageBody.length', 5),

//Return the opposite to make "disabled" false
isDisabled: Ember.computed('messageIsValid','emailIsValid', function(){
  return !(this.get('messageIsValid') && this.get('emailIsValid'));
})
```

In the hbs file you need something like this:

```
  <button disabled={{isDisabled}}>Send message</button>
```